# Vue.js 3 - Enabling/Disabling Form Elements via Computed Properties

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm using Vue.js 3 and attempting to disable form elements during an ajax post, then enable them again once the post is complete (regardless of success).

Setting the isFormSubmitting property to true when beginning the submission works. The issue I'm having is that setting it back to false leaves the element disabled.

Here's how I'm binding to the disabled property

```
<textarea v-bind:disabled='isFormDisabled' v-bind:value="model.description" class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
```

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    const App = {
        data() {
            return {
                model: @(Html.Raw(Model.Json)),
                isFormSubmitting: false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            isFormDisabled: function () {
                return this.isFormSubmitting;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            processData() {

                this.isFormSubmitting = true;

                var json = JSON.stringify(this.model);

                console.log('isFormDisabled = ' + this.isFormDisabled);

                $.post(
                    {
                        url: '@Url.Action("SaveNewTicket", "DriverTickets")',
                        data: json,
                        success: function ()
                        {
                            console.log('submitted');
                            this.isFormSubmitting = false;
                            console.log('isFormDisabled = ' + this.isFormDisabled);
                        },
                        fail: function ()
                        {
                            console.log('failed');
                            this.isFormSubmitting = false;
                            console.log('isFormDisabled = ' + this.isFormDisabled);
                        },
                        done: function ()
                        {
                            console.log('done');
                            this.isFormSubmitting = false;
                            console.log('isFormDisabled = ' + this.isFormDisabled);
                        }
                    });
            },
        }
    }

    const app = Vue.createApp(App);
    const vm = app.mount('#app');

</script>
```

Here's my console output:

```
isFormDisabled = true
submitted
isFormDisabled = undefined
```

I've also tried binding directly to a property. When I do that, I get false back from the output instead of undefined, but the disabled attribute remains on the form.

I'm admittedly not a very good front-end developer so critiques unrelated to the problem itself are also welcome.

Comment: Your `$post` callback functions should be [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pointed out already by @shob the reason it's not working most likely because you're declaring the ajax callbacks using `function(){}` notation instead of using `()=>{}`

The misconception is that they are interchangeable, but that's not the case. What `()=>{}` does is equivalent to `function(){}.bind(this)`, that is it binds the context of the function to the current context. That's also why you can't use arrow functions for things like computed, because the `this` context is expected to come from the caller. Anyway, you can fix it, preferably using arrow functions (for better readability mostly), or by adding `bind(this)` if you're not feeling comfortable with the arrow function definitions.

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      model: @(Html.Raw(Model.Json)),
      isFormSubmitting: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isFormDisabled: function () {
      return this.isFormSubmitting;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    processData() {

      this.isFormSubmitting = true;

      var json = JSON.stringify(this.model);

      console.log('isFormDisabled = ' + this.isFormDisabled);

      $.post(
        {
          url: '@Url.Action("SaveNewTicket", "DriverTickets")',
          data: json,
          success: function ()
          {
            console.log('submitted');
            this.isFormSubmitting = false;
            console.log('isFormDisabled = ' + this.isFormDisabled);
          }.bind(this),
          fail: function ()
          {
            console.log('failed');
            this.isFormSubmitting = false;
            console.log('isFormDisabled = ' + this.isFormDisabled);
          }.bind(this),
          done: function ()
          {
            console.log('done');
            this.isFormSubmitting = false;
            console.log('isFormDisabled = ' + this.isFormDisabled);
          }.bind(this)
        });
    },
  }
}

const app = Vue.createApp(App);
const vm = app.mount('#app');
```